# Changing a string in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change "Tag" to "Brand" on WooCommerce. I've Googled, read about gettext, tried several other options but none have worked.

The line of code in the theme is

```
<?php echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
```

What's the most proper (upgrade-proof) way to change that word "**Tag**"? I know I shouldn't edit the theme directly.

Should I edit the .mo and .po files? I edited the .po but it didn't take on the change (I'm supposed to generate a .mo afterwards somehow?)

Other links said to add a filter to my wp theme's functions.php.

WooCommerce themselves recommend a plugin http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/, but my server runs out of memory and can't complete the rescan process.

I'm confused at the number of options and workarounds that are needed to change a string. Did I miss any other options?

Comment: I never seen or worked with a woocommerce platform, but isn't woocommerce just like wordpress? If so, you can do this by accessing settings on admin's page, and then permalinks. And then you'll be able to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.po/.mo` option is feasible if your site is in [another language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language), and yes you need to [generate the `.mo` file](http://poedit.net) which is the one that WP reads.

A simpler way would be creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and substituting this file through it.

Another option is to use [this plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3675/12615), adjusting the context to `frontend` and the post type to `product`. But beware that's an expensive plugin as it goes through **all** translatable strings of a page (and more).

Finally, you could use jQuery or JS to do it. Using the hook `wp_footer` and some [Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to target your specific page(s).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @brasofilo. I'll look into all your links. This is exactly what is giving me headaches: so many different ways to accomplish this one little change. There is no one 'correct' way. I wish it was like Joomla, just change one line in the language file and I'm done :/